# Colorize UIMenuItem?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

in `UIMenuItem` Is there any way to change the color of an `UIMenuItem`? I'm adding a "preview" menu item on a black collection view and would like to have the `UIMenuItem` appear in a different color. Any hints? I've searched up and down and found nothing.

Comment: @sagarcool89 I doubt that be impossible (in programming, something is very rarely impossible), at most you have to do some (not only )reverse engineering.